# How to set NDK environment variable in Windows?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I got this kind of error in Windows 32 bit .

```
"C:\\Users\\NDK\\android-ndk-r12b\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cpufeatures' in import path    
jni/Android.mk:46: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:
```

How to do resolve it?

Comment: File->ProjectStructure->NDKLocation

Answer (score 4):

Do the following, hope it helps:

1- Right click on My Computer and select Properties, or Press Windows + Break:
[image]

2- Select Advanced system settings, then Environment variables:
[image]

3- Select Path variable, then Press Edit:
[image]

4- Add NDK directory path to the list like the following picture:
[image]

Press Ok, and close all open windows.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/33

You need to import `android/cpufeatures`, not `cpufeatures`.